# Calculating wage by hours worked

Tags: math, datetime, vb6

Hey all, i am trying to figure out how to calculate the wage for an employee when they clock out. This is the code i am currently using:

```
 Dim theStartTime As Date
 Dim theEndTime As Date
 Dim totalTime As String

 theStartTime = "16:11:06"
 theEndTime = "18:22:01"
 totalTime = Format(CDbl((theEndTime - theStartTime) * 24), "#0.0")
```

So workable hours would be: 2h 11m

Right now, with my calculation code above, i get 2.2. What would i need to add in order to get it to calculate the correct time of 2:11 instead of 2:20?

David

Comment: 2 hours and 11 minutes is awfully close to 2.2 hours.  (off by a minute).

Comment: And if you did #0.00 you might see it's something like 2.18

Comment: Ah, yes, putting #.## works better. But it's still giving me 2h 18m when it should give 2h 11m? So its giving them an extra 7 minutes of time not being worked.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Note that 2.2 hours is *not* 2:20, it's 2:12.

Change

```
Format(CDbl((theEndTime - theStartTime) * 24), "#0.0")
```

to

```
Format(theEndTime - theStartTime, "h:mm")
```

You're getting the right value, just rounding it off when you print. `theEndTime - theStartTime` is a time span equal to the difference between the two times. As you discovered, multiplying it by 24 will give you the number of hours different. However, you then have to divide by 24 again to use date/time formatting.

Check out all the ways to [format dates and time in VB6](http://www.vb6.us/tutorials/formating-dates-and-times-vb6).

Comment: How would i add a wage to that output of 2:11? The wage is 10.50.

Comment: Just wait until you have to factor in overtime. That is a major mess, considering the rules differ by location and in some cases by day of the week.

Comment: `paycheck = (theEndTime - theStartTime) * 24 * wage`. I hope that this is a project, and not something you're really going to use in your business. Don't forget about things like daylight savings time, because I'm not sure how `(theEndTime - theStartTime)` will be handled.

Answer (score 1):

First, I highly suggest going to the .NET framework (with it's easy-to-use TimeSpan class) if possible.

But, dealing in VB6 you should be able to use the [DATEDIFF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b5xbyt6f%28VS.90%29.aspx) function (and it's been many years since I've touched VB6 so the specific syntax might be a bit off

```
Dim iHours As Integer, iMins As Integer
iMins = DateDiff("n", theStartTime, theEndTime)
iHours = iMins / 60
iMins = iMins Mod 60
```

Comment: Some of us don't have the luxury of upgrading all of our legacy software to .Net. (Though I too would recommend it if possible.)

Comment: I would expect 11 in iMins and the 2 in the iHours.

Answer (score 0):

You should also try casting it to the `Currency` type which can represent all numeric values *(within 4 digits to the left of decimal point and 15 digits to the right)*.

```
Format(CCur((theEndTime - theStartTime) * 24), "#0.00")
```

Comment: The problem here is not rounding, it's representation.

Comment: @Daniel - That is what I said didn't I?

Comment: Sorry - I worded my comment wrong; the problem is formatting of the output. Casting to a `Currency` wouldn't solve the problem that 2.2 hours is not 2:20.

Comment: @Daniel - For this specific case, but what if the output was `2.1` which cannot be represented appropriately as a double?

Comment: True, but the OP is looking for accuracy to the minute - I don't think `Currency` is worth the trouble, in my opinion.

Comment: Daniel is correct. Like i stated above, the output currently is 2h 18m but i need 2h 11m as it really **should** be.